# Forward hostname to EC2 instances behind Elastic Loadbalancer in elastic beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, hostname, elastic-beanstalk

I'd like the applications running on EC2 instances to know which url the original request came from. Is this possible with an Elastic Loadbalancer?

I'm assuming passing the hostname through would be possible but I can't find the configuration options anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The requested hostname is included in the `Host:` header.

Elastic Load Balancer will forward all headers on to the underlying EC2 instances. There is no configuration to allow or disallow headers.

CloudFront configuration allows you to blacklist and whitelist headers.